# Creating a Tortoise SVN repository with the right files

Tags: svn

I'm a little new to SVN creation. Usually this is handled for us by IT.

I'm creating a product of my own, and I know there are files you don't include in a typical SVN, (.DLL's,BIN folders etc...)

My question is, can I create a repository by only selecting certain folders and files, and is there a guide on governance for what should and should not be included?

I have Tortoise SVN, and am handling subversion on my local machine for now.

Project is a SharePoint 2010 app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. You can create a root project folder for all your subfiles and subfolders in the `trunk` of your SVN and only `commit` what you need to by right clicking such files/folders manually via Tortoise menu.

As for files that you don't want on svn, you can add them to `svn:ignore` via the turtoise SVN menu (Right click -> add to ignore list).

For Sharepoint files that shouldn't be committed and other related SVN best practices, this link has a pretty complete list I believe:

[What paths should I ignore when checking a SharePoint project into Subversion?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24687/what-paths-should-i-ignore-when-checking-a-sharepoint-project-into-subversion)

For more how-tos and other SVN operations regarding turtoiseSVN and other clients, this link is pretty easy to follow and comprehensive:
http://people.senecac.on.ca/wayne.bryan/svc.html